# Writing Binary String to file

Tags: php, string, file, binary, zeromq

I m getting a request, when i use `echo` it prints it out on the shell and everything is awesome.

I want to write human readable string to file.

When i try to write these messages to file. i see binary string.

like this:

```
6^@8^@3^@7^@8^@1^@0^@,^@,^@1^@1^@b^@c^@d^@9^@0^@f^@-^@e^@3^@3^@a^@-^@4^@e^@0^@5^@-^@9^@e^@3^@d^@-^@5^@f^@a^@1^@8^@3^@4^@f^@d^@5^@e^@7^@,^@,^@:^@:^@1^@,^@M^@o^@z^@i^@l^@l^@a^@/^@5^@.^@0^@ ^@(^@W^@i^@n^@d^@o^@w^@s^@ ^@N^@T^@ ^@6^@.^@1^@;^@
 ^@W^@O^@W^@6^@4^@;^@ ^@r^@v^@:^@9^@.^@0^@.^@1^@)^@ ^@G^@e^@c^@k^@o^@/^@2^@0^@1^@0^@0^@1^@0^@1^@ ^@F^@i^@r^@e^@f^@o^@x^@/^@9^@.^@0^@.^@1^@,^@F^@i^@r^@e^@f^@o^@x^@,^@9^@.^@0^@,^@W^@i^@n^@d^@o^@w^@s^@,^@,^@0^@,^@0^@,^@0^@,^@0^@,^@0^@,^@,^@
 ^@:^@:^@1^@,^@ ^@1^@/^@2^@1^@/^@2^@0^@1^@2^@ ^@5^@:^@4^@5^@:^@5^@0^@ ^@P^@M^@
```

but i expect this:

```
6837817,,01497aed-181b-4054-b68f-3b41b4e707fc,,::1,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1,Firefox,9.0,Windows,,0,0,0,0,0,, ::1, 1/21/2012 5:45:51 PM
```

ok i saw that there are methods like `pack` and `unpack` to get string from binary string but i failed.

```
<?php

$context = new ZMQContext();
$receiver = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$receiver->bind("tcp://*:5557");

$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');

while(true){ 
$str = $receiver->recv();

echo $str."\n";

file_put_contents('foo.txt', $str);

//fwrite($fp, $str."\n");


}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

How can i get this done? I just wanted to write the string to file:(

Also, is this an expensive operation?

Comment: Why are you (un)packing to begin with? What is that string? What's wrong with simply writing it to a file?

Comment: i see crap . i mean binary when i write to file. when i print out with echo, i get string representation but not in a file.

Comment: What exactly do you see in the file? And more importantly, how are you checking what's in the file? And what do you *expect* to see?

Comment: @deceze see edit. I m checking with `less`

Comment: Why don't you just skip the packing and just write the string to the file?

Comment: Then please show us a *complete, concise example* that reproduces the issue. Input, output.

Comment: input is coming from zmq and output is in the question.

Comment: I don't see where you're *outputting* (`echo`) the string in your code. I see that you're decoding it twice though for some reason. I don't even know which variable exactly holds the input...

Comment: OK, so in what format are you getting data from ZMQ then?

Comment: never mind. i figured it out. thanks for downvote. very generous of u.

Comment: Dude, your question is still unclear and not really answerable, even after a tried to pull the necessary information from you. The accepted answer is also the one I gave and which is now even in your question. This question is not really clear or helpful to others. If you have figured out what's wrong, you should write that up as your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there isn't binary data, but a different encoding for text. It's some form of `UCS-2` I'd say. So you can "decode" it with:

```
 $string = iconv("UCS-2LE", "UTF-8", $string);
 file_put_contents(...);
```

See [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) and [`UCS-2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) `FF FE`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with file_put_contents? http://php.net/file_put_contents

```
file_put_contents('file/path.ext', $str);
```